# Problem with authentication in firebase and react

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to do firebase email/password auth with react and I'm getting an error:

"_firebaseWEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1.default.onAuthStateChanged is not a function
TypeError: _firebaseWEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1.default.onAuthStateChanged is not a function"

So I guess there must be something wrong with my AuthContext.js code:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import auth from "../firebase";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  function login(email, password) {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    login,
    signup,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Tried to find solution myself for 3 hours. Unfortunately not successful :(

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Firebase SDK version 10, which defaults to using a modular syntax for its API calls. So in that SDK `onAuthStateChanged` is a top-level function, rather than a method on the `auth` service.

For more on this, see the code sample in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#web-modular-api) (be sure to use the <kbd>Web modular API</kbd> tab as that's what you're using), and the documentation on [upgrading from the namespaced API to the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to upgrade my code like in the documentation but it didn't work. So I was looking for some typo but it seemed to be exactly like in doc and tutorials. After few hours i did sth that made my code run with no errors. The thing is i'm not sure if i can do that. In "firebase.js" instead of "export const auth = getAuth(app); and "export default app" I changed it to "const auth = getAuth(app)" and "export dafault auth". Can I export auth as default or i shouldn't do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the importation of **onAuthStateChanged**. Instead of using **auth.onAuthStateChanged()**, you should import it like this:

```
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
```

This allows you to use **onAuthStateChanged** as a function directly. You can find more details on how to import it correctly in [the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

By making this change, you'll be able to use onAuthStateChanged as intended and avoid the error.

Comment: ```useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);``` so i got sth like this now with the import you mentioned and still same error

Comment: I also tried to add if else inside like in this doc